# WHERE clause wants collection of collections of relationships, but I can only provide a collection of relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to query the neighborhood at a certain distance around a topic node.  The twist, is I do not want to follow relationships from nodes with a certain attribute.  Any query needs to run on graphs in the millions of nodes and edges (which rules out collecting paths).

I think I have a query that will do it:

```
MATCH (topic: attribute)-[r:describedBy|influences*0..2]-(n: attribute) 
WHERE id(topic) IN [239930]
WITH n, r as rels, topic
MATCH (n: attribute)-[r:describedBy|influences]->()
WHERE NOT n.key in ['enrichment', 'classification'] AND r in rels
WITH n, r, collect(r) as rels, topic
MATCH path = shortestpath((topic)-[*..2]-(n))
WHERE extract(rel IN rels(path) | rel) as r WHERE r in rels 
WITH r, extract(n IN nodes(path) | n) as nodes
RETURN count(DISTINCT r), count(DISTINCT nodes)
```

The problem is trying to compare collections of relationships.  Specifically:

```
Type mismatch: expected Collection<Collection<Relationship>> but was Collection<Relationship> (line 8, column 43 (offset: 369))
"WHERE extract(rel IN rels(path) | rel) in rels "
```

I have run into this 'collection of collection of relationships' problem in multiple attempts to create this query.

How can I either A: fix the `collection of collection of relationships` problem or B: rewrite the query such that it returns the neighborhood around one or more nodes at a given distance and without following relationships from nodes with specific properties?

[EDIT]
Based on @cybersam's recommendation, the query is now:

`WHERE NOT n.key in ['enrichment', 'classification'] AND r in rels
WITH n, r, collect(r) as rels, topic
MATCH path = shortestpath((topic)-[*..2]-(n))
WHERE [r2 IN rels(path) WHERE r2 in rels]
WITH r, extract(n IN nodes(path) | n) as nodes
RETURN count(DISTINCT r), count(DISTINCT nodes)`

The problem is that this returns 47242 relationships and 47242 edges.  It would appear it's returning the edges from the collection of path rather than from the sub-query above, (which has a count of 100103 edges or so from previous experimentation).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have syntax errors in this line of your question's query:

```
WHERE extract(rel IN rels(path) | rel) as r WHERE r in rels
```

You probably actually used `WITH` instead of the leading `WHERE` -- as that would result in the error you reported:

```
WITH extract(rel IN rels(path) | rel) as r WHERE r in rels
```

Now, assuming that I am correct above:

1. The result of `extract(rel IN rels(path) | rel)` is the same as `rels(path)`, which makes using `extract()` a waste of time. I suspect that you actually meant to extract something else. Note that, currently, the resulting `r`  is a **collection of relationships**.
2. Since `r` is a collection of relationships, the `r in rels` clause would require that `rels` be a **collection of collection of relationships**. But it is actually a collection of relationships, hence the error.

The solution might be as easy as fixing your `extract()` clause. I don't know enough about your problem domain to know how to do that, but hopefully this is enough to point you in the right direction.

[EDIT]

Based on the clarification from @Gabe, this might be the correct replacement for the line in question:

```
WHERE all(r IN rels(path) WHERE r in rels)
```

Comment: The double where line should have been `WHERE extract(rel IN rels(path) | rel) in rels` or, with your simplification, `WHERE rels(path) IN rels`.  This still produces the "Type mismatch: expected Collection<Collection<Relationship>> but was Collection<Relationship>" error.  Unfortunately, `WHERE extract(rels(path)) IN rels" produces the error: "Unknown function 'extract'"

Comment: See the [EDIT] to my answer.